# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pwd' -- airflow python

Tags: python, airflow

I want to install web UI for airflow using

```
airflow webserver  --port 1080
```

but I get this error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pwd'

what a good way to fix it?

Comment: What happened when you tried reading and following the installation instructions for airflow?

Comment: Are you running on Windows?

Comment: Same issue And I am installing it on Windows. Looks like windows not supported but did not found any clear statement about that in documentation.

Answer (score 7):

`pwd` module is not available on Windows.

You can either try to use WSL or running it in a Docker container.

Comment: Didn't found anywhere in Airflow site that it not supposed to be installed on Windows. is there any statement about that? (just in case you know)

Comment: Didn't found either, in the `running-airflow-locally` section they seem to assume you're using a Unix based machine.

Comment: Looks like so. Strange this is not stated explicitly. Docker to the rescue