# Airflow Installation on Local machine

Tags: python, dll, airflow

I am trying to install Airflow on Windows 11.

[image: code]

I completed the installation until the above screenshot. But when I am trying to go for the next command that is "airflow standalone", I am getting the error as

> "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _sqlite3: The specified
> module could not be found." Unable to create database and initiate the
> airflow.

I am using Visual Studio Code for installation.

I was expecting the database would be created and Airflow would open after the final steps.

Comment: If there is a conflict, you can use `conda install sqlite` to resolve.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am having the same issue and it appears Airflow is simply not supported on Windows. It requires some Python module ("pwd") which is not available on Windows. From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67030075/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-pwd-airflow-python

Answer (score 1):

`astro-cli` is a free, easy way to install Apache Airflow and have a data pipeline running in under five minutes.

Please follow this [documentation](https://docs.astronomer.io/astro/cli/install-cli).